# Stateless Authentication Library in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, authentication, single-sign-on, stateless, passport.js

I believe the best practice for RESTful API's is to be stateless. I read abit about stateless authentication but am not totally clear how to implement it (looks like a mess of tokens etc). PassportJS is a nice authentication library, but its not stateless? Is there some kind of library that helps me create stateless API's (with authentication)? I will want to use SSO (single sign on) like Google, Twitter etc. so it will be nice if the library handles that for me (like PassportJS does).

Comment: When you say stateless, I assume you mean no session info is stored about the user on the server side. If you want this, you can use  `cookiesession` middleware provided by connect/express libraries. Probably this is what you want but can you elaborate on your interpretation of stateless authentication, so that I can help.

Comment: @user568109, you are right, stateless meaning no session info on server. `cookiesession` looks like what I need but, I still need to figure the authentication part. PassportJS an awesome authentication library uses sessions, wonder if its possible to make it work with `cookiesession` or somehow make PassportJS stateless?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I am currently developing a REST API and using PassportJS Basic Auth (for dev purposes) with no sessions. You can tell the strategy to not use sessions:

```
passport.authenticate( 'basic', { 'session' : false } )
passport.authenticate( 'bearer', { 'session' : false } )
passport.authenticate( 'token', { 'session' : false } )
```

See [here](http://passportjs.org/guide/oauth2-api/) at the bottom.

Comment: I am kind of new to this. If I want users to authenticate via 3rd parties such as Google, GitHub etc, which I believe use OAuth 2 also, how do I configure this? How does providers (Google, Facebook, Twitter) relate to API's (Basic, OAuth, OAuth 2)?

Answer (score 6):

@fakewaffle is right. You can make passport stateless by setting session to false.

I have developed an Oauth2 server using oauth2rize. https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize/.
I use it provide access tokens to client, which are then sent with every request in `authorization` header. These tokens are stored in database and are therefore stateless.

You can of course use other providers to authenticate user and provide access token to client.

Passport.js provides multiple authentication providers which can be used to authenticate via 3rd party providers such as facebook, twitter, etc.
Here is link to facebook auth provider http://passportjs.org/guide/facebook/.

Does this answer the question or is there something else you want to do?

Comment: `oauth2orize` is something I can use if I want to create an OAuth provider? If I want to allow my users to login/register via Google/GitHub/etc, I will use the respective PassportJS providers right? If so I want to make them stateless, how should that work? Its not documented, so can I use: `passport.authenticate( 'google', { 'session' : false } )`?

Comment: Also, "*tokens are stored in database and are therefore stateless*": so I could use `redis-sessions` with no changes to the code in PassportJS's side of things and everything will be "stateless"?

Comment: Yes I think you can use `redis-sessions`, although I have not used redis myself. And yes, `oauth2rize` is used to create your own OAuth provider. Also can you explain what exactly do you mean by stateless, so I can answer with bit more confidence.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly: npm install simple-stateless-auth-library@1.1.0